# Avoid `\begin{center}` environment when including external PDF image

Tags: org-mode, latex, images, pdf, graphics

By default a code such as this in `org-mode`

```
[[foo.pdf]]
```

will produce the following code in the exported `.tex` document

```
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[width=.9\linewidth]{foo.pdf}
\end{center}
```

How can I stop `org-mode`'s exporter from adding the `\begin{center} \end{center}` environment. I am using the `memoir` class and I'd rather use `\centerfloat`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
#+ATTR_LATEX: :center nil
...
```

Do `C-h i g(org)Images in LaTeX export` where you'll find this:

> The LaTeX export back-end centers all images by default.  Setting
> ‘:center’ to ‘nil’ disables centering.  To disable centering globally,
> set ‘org-latex-images-centered’ to ‘nil’.

as well as more information about other possible attributes.

Comment: Hello Nick, thank you for the answer and for the tip on `Info`. I keep forgetting about it and I search on the web instead. But `Info` is sooo easy to use... Don't know why `g` doesn't work though. It happens in the most general index. When I move to `Org Mode` `g` does work and with it I can choose the node I want.

Comment: `C-h i` starts up Info but you may have started it already, in which case it goes to whatever Info node you were looking at last. `g` goes from whatever Info page you are currently on, to the top Info page you specify in the parenthesized part. So if you are looking at some Info page on e.g. `emacs` and you say `g(org)`, you will end up at the top level page of the Org manual. If you say `g(org)Images in latex export` you will end up on that section.

Comment: I see, but from `C-h i`, i.e., for `Info` itself you can't use `g` to navigate thru the different entries there, i.e., from `auto-indent-mode` (within or under `Emacs`) to `Ledger3` (within or under `User Applications`).

Comment: Yes, yoiu can  (or you should be able to). Now I don't see a node called `auto-indent-mode` under Emacs, but if I am at, say, `Choosing File modes` and I type `C-h i  g(ledger3)Keeping a journal` I end up at the right place (and there is completion along the way: `C-h i g(le TAB)Ke TAB a TAB` does the same thing).